# Случайное событие с вероятностью 0.1

Tags: c#, теория-вероятностей

Мне нужно что бы функция возвращала true с вероятностью 0,1. Как я понимаю можно сделать примерно так:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    if (rnd.Next(1, 10) == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Прав ли я? Или нужно сделать это как то по другому.

Comment: Как то так да. Можно еще через `rnd.NextDouble()<0.1` или `>0.9`, но это уже вариации на тему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс `Random` генерирует псевдослучайные числа с равной вероятностью в заданном диапазоне. Равная вероятность гарантируется только в рамках конкретного экземпляра `Random`. Если каждый раз создавать новый экземпляр, вы рискуете получить одинаковые числа на выходе из `Random.Next()`, и вероятность будет далеко не 0.1, а скорее неопределенная. Так что создайте один экземпляр `Random` и используйте только его, и учтите, что `Random.Next(minValue, maxValue)` генерирует числа в диапазоне `[minValue, maxValue)`.

```
private static readonly Random rnd = new Random();
...
return rnd.Next(0, 10) == 0; // или rnd.Next(10) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятность рассчитывается как отношение числа случившихся событий к общему числу возможных событий. Если мы генерируем с помощью Rand одно число в промежутке от 1 до 10, то мы действительно получим каждое из этих чисел с вероятностью, равной 1/10. Но вызывать нужно

```
rnd.Next(1,11)
```

т.к.второй параметр указывает **эксклюзивную верхнюю границу**, т.е. макс.число, которое вы при этом сможете получить, на единицу меньше переданного в параметре.

Если нужно переопределить метод генерации числа, чтобы числа возвращались с разной вероятностью, можно переопределить методы [Sample и Next](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.random.sample?view=netframework-4.8) базового класса [Random](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Мне кажется, что очень уместно смотрелся бы код, как именно вып предлагаете решить вопрос, пока что больше похоже на очень смутное и общее указание как решить задачу. На stackoverflow это обычно считается комментарием, нежели ответом.